# The session is invalid because the user logged out

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, facebook, api

I have a situation here and I'm still cracking my head on how to solve it.

Here's the scenario:

1. User visits my website
2. User clicks on Login to FB (in order for my App to retrieve his FB info via the Api graph).
3. User logins with his FB credential and Approve the App.
4. User is redirected back to the same page that he clicks on the Login to FB button (in step 2, because the button, will invoke the method RedirectToFacebookAuthorization() ).
5. User then logs out from Facebook.com (my website hasn't implement any log out button for this scenario).
6. User has successfully logged out from his FB account, he revisit my website.
7. My website throws out an exception message as below:

Exception Details: Facebook.Utility.FacebookException: The session is invalid because the user logged out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an exception, and you do know why it has been thrown. the only way is to handle it in your code, logging out the user in your site too.

Try to search some variants of checking this error, like [this](http://cordal.posterous.com/session-key-invalid-or-no-longer-valid-using):

```
if(ex.Message == "The session is invalid because the user logged out") 
{
    //timeout caused by user logging out of FB (auth token remains in qstring) 
    Session.Remove("Facebook_session_key"); 
    Session.Remove("Facebook_userId");
    Session.Remove("Facebook_session_expires");

    //redirect to login
    Response.Redirect(@"http://www.Facebook.com/login.php?api_key=" + fbService.ApplicationKey + @"&v=1.0\");
}
```

Also you should check the `ErrorType` property of the [exception](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/Facebook-Developer-Toolkit/Version-3.01/Release/All/Facebook/Facebook/Utility/FacebookException.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// A value representing the specific type of error returned by Facebook.
/// </summary>
public enum ErrorType
{
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    Unknown = 1,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    ServiceUnavailable = 2,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    RequestLimit = 4,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    Timeout = 102,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    Signing = 104,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    InvalidUser = 110,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    InvalidAlbum = 120,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    UserNotVisible = 210,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    AlbumNotVisible = 220,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    PhotoNotVIsible = 221,
    ///<summary>
    ///</summary>
    InvaldFQLSyntax = 601
}
```